# How to destroy screen on navigation.onback()

Tags: react-native, navigation, unmount

I'm using a stack navigator and on

```
<HeaderBackButton onPress={_ => navigation.goBack(null)}
```

I want to destroy current screen, I've seen other replacements like using .replace instead of .navigate but I want to do such thing on .goBack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Will it destroy my current screen?

Comment: this.goBack('here your wanted page name');

Comment: You don't get my point, navigation is fine, I want to unmount or finish current screen, cause next time whenever I come back to this current screen I get preview of last loaded data